# NSNotificationCenter not working on iPhone side of Universal App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, ios4

I'm working on a Universal application for iPad and iPhone.  I've got a shared app delegate, an iPad app delegate (subclasses the shared) and an iPhone app delegate (also subclasses the shared) - all based on the template in XCode.  The app also has a shared view controller for navigation. In the iPad it's used as the master view controller in a `SplitViewController`.  In the iPhone app, it's shown as the root view controller of a `UINavigationController`.

In my shared app delegate, I'm grabbing some `JSON` from my web server to configure the app and when I've completed parsing that data I post a notification to `NSNotificationCenter` (defaultCenter).

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kDataReady object:nil];
```

The shared view controller is an observer for this notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
            selector:@selector(onDataReady:) 
             name:kDataReady 
              object:nil];
```

When I run the app on the iPad, the shared view controller is picking up this notification and calling the selector appropriately.  When run on the iPhone, it's not.  The common classes between iPhone and iPad are instantiated in the same order and I can verify this by the console logs.  I haven't a clue as to why this isn't working as expected.  Help!

Answer (score 1):

Is the `addObserver` method certainly called on the iPhone? Just because it's subclassed doesn't mean that the necessary super calls are in place.

Comment: The addObserver method isn't called on the shared app delegate.  The shared app delegate posts the notification.  The view controller in common to both iPad and iPhone is adding the observer in it's init method.  Same init method being called on both devices but only the iPad works.

Comment: have you verified (with debugger and all) that the addObserver is really executed? Also, is the Constant defined upstream enough to be exactly the same?

Comment: Oh, and one last point: is onDataReady:(id)sender really defined in the iPhone Viewcontroller? To give you better help, it would be good to have the .h files of some of those classes....

Comment: Not sure how to verify addObserver is working, since that's within NSNotificationCenter.  I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: And the onDataReady method is defined.  It's the same viewcontroller in iPhone as in iPad.  Only iPad working.